# How to write MIN MAX operation using ANTLR lexer and parser?

Tags: java, antlr3

For my project I have to define a new grammar rule while will calculate the MIN or MAX of giving argument.Below is the example.

```
MIN(3, 4, 5, 6) = 3

MIN(3, 5, 6, 7, 8) = 3
```

Basically the problem I am facing is defining the TreeWalker function, where it should take variable number of argument.

The language I am using is Java.

OK I will put a snippet of the code which is more or less similar but not the exact one

Parser Rule:

```
minExpr
  : MIN^ LPAREN! minExprStmt RPAREN!
  ;

minExprStmt
  : digitExpr (COMA! digitExpr)+
  ;
```

Lexer Rule:

```
token{
  MIN="MIN"
}
```

TreeWalker:

```
getNode return [double r]
 {ExpNode a=null; r = null;}
 : #(MIN a=getNode)
      {try{r=new MinExpNode();}catch(Exception e){throw new RecognitionException(e.toString();}}
```

So now what I want is that MinExpNode should take a list or an array of ExpNode in constructor, which in turn will give the computed value of each expNode.

I am not using any external libraries for this.

Comment: Are you using an external library to lex and parse, or are you parsing on your own? Where will you put the grammar rule that you need?

Comment: @nmore Read the question and the tags. He is using ANTLR.

Comment: Can you post your grammar?

Comment: We can't answer your question without looking at the grammar that you are using

Comment: I am sorry to reply late, was not having access to stackoverflow. Please let me know if you need more information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after some research I think I found a solutions, 
TreeWalker Code:

```
getNode return [double r]
  {ExpNode a=null; List<ExpNode> list = new ArrayLis<ExpNode>(); r = null;}
  : #(MIN a=getNode {list.add(a);} ({ExpNode b = getNode; list.add(b);})*)
       {try{r=new MinExpNode(list);}catch(Exception e){throw new RecognitionException(e.toString();}}
```

But still if you can suggest me a better one it would be very helpful.